# Let's shape this site with Vote to Close!

Tags: discussion

We are getting a lot of questions that are clearly off-topic according to the FAQ, but they are still getting answers.  I think that if we want to make this site work as a topical resource, we need to be aggressive with our close votes (while being polite and explanatory in the comments as to reasons).  Any fuzziness will be revealed in the close/open votes.

It sure would help, a lot, if there was the option to vote to close with "Belongs on".  Even if it didn't transfer anything (maybe auto-populated comments?) for now.

Comment: Can you give some examples? I love clicking "close"...

Comment: Please see my question today for example: http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/144/web-apps-questions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think right now we also need to focus on the kinds of questions we want. There are some questions that I saw that would (probably) be on topic for SO, but I did not vote to close each one. The same thing goes for topics that would probably be a good match for SF.

The criteria I use is "Can this question be answered adequately by the members of this site?", not so much "Would the asker get better answers on another". Likewise, if its something that a webmaster has to deal with in their day to day job, I see no reason to ship a question to a trilogy site *just because* it would also be appropriate there.

Granted, some judgement and discretion comes into play. I'd vote to close specific programming questions, but not questions that happen to apply to programming too.

What I'm most concerned about is repeating some mistakes that were made on SO in regards to questions that quickly become lists or discussions. Yes, a list of payment processors would be handy, but might become unwieldy over time. The same thing applies to questions that ask for opinions rather than answers. Just wait until people drag support arguments with their web host to this site, we have to make it clear that we're not a place to hang up dirty laundry, we're a place to ask questions and get answers.

To get out of beta, we have to ensure a steady stream of great questions and answers. If we get out of beta, Jeff has already mentioned that we'll (probably) have some means to ship questions to the sites that we overlap.

A lot of broken windows isn't going to help get us out of beta. I'm not saying that's what we have, but its something we need to consciously avoid :)