# Moderator Nominations

Tags: discussion, moderators

This site does not have *any* discussions about selecting Moderators.

I am in the process of creating positions for Moderators *Pro Tem* from each community. But I need your help. We need nominations right now. A lack of leadership will become actively harmful to this community.

**Here are some basic guidelines:**

- Use this thread. Each nomination should be a separate answer. Link the name to the user's profile so we can see their activity.
- The nominee should indicate their acceptance by commenting on (or indeed editing) the answer.
- Self nominations are okay.
- Vote on users you feel will make **[good Moderator candidates](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)**. **Please be civil and respectful.**

We are looking for members who are deeply engaged in the community development; members who:

- Are currently a registered user in good standing.
- Have a reasonably high reputation score to indicate active, consistent participation.
- Exhibit patience and fairness at all times in their questions, answers, and comments.
- Lead by example, showing respect for their fellow community members in everything they write.
- Want the responsibility. Moderators volunteer a lot of time and work. Its can be hugely rewarding experience but it isn't always a popularity contest.

Bonus points for:

- Being the site proposer or heavily involved in the proposal process.
- Members who referred a lot of followers/committers on Area 51.
- Members with participation in *both* meta and the parent site (i.e. interest in both community building and expertise in the field).

These users will be contacted and three of them will be selected to act as Moderators until the formal elections.

They will:

- Have access to the tools to perform the duties of Moderation
- Have access to a special chat room where we will collectively work through the challenges of moderation and community self-policing
- Drive the process of selecting the site's attributes (domain names, design issues, the FAQ, etc.)
- Help get publicity for their sites and organize their communities

Basically, **they will have the ear of the Stack Exchange team for anything we can do to help this site succeed.** They will act as a liaison — a job that "links" Stack Overflow with this community.

Moderators solve a basic scalability problem. We can't be in each site, identifying the issues and helping each community grow. That's where Moderators come in; they make sure communities are enabled to solve these problems where they can and elicit our help when necessary.

Comment: Per Jeff's guidelines, should not this topic be Community Wiki?

Answer (score 10):

I nominate [Tim Post](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/users/55/tim-post) as a moderator for Pro Webmasters.  This is the first time that I've been active on a Stack Exchange site (answered a [couple questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/98054/jasonbirch) on SO, but wasn't a great fit for my expertise), and his guidance has been invaluable.

Comment: Thanks for the nomination. I'm really excited about this site, I think its taking off very well and I already see a nice community forming. I'm happy to do what the community can't when/as needed.

Comment: +1 he is a great efford for the whole community

Answer (score 4):

I nominate myself, mainly because I'm online in the timezone GMT +10 which means that I'm online when the site is mostly off-peak, which means that someone's gotta keep an eye open when everyone else is in bed.

<sub>I also miss the "edit" and the "tools" button that I have on ServerFault, and this is the quickest way to get them back ;)</sub>

Comment: You come from a land down under?

Comment: Yes I do. I also eat vegemite.

Comment: We're close, I'm two hours behind you.

Comment: I second your nomination.  Good point about the time zone.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it

Answer (score 4):

I nominate [jasonbirch](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/users/180/jasonbirch) because he is constantly active on the Meta site and seems to have a good clear idea of what's going on and what should/shouldn't be going on. Also his [question regarding closing](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146/lets-shape-this-site-with-vote-to-close) made me realise that we're not working hard enough to define the site.

Comment: Thanks for the nomination.  I do care about the health of this site and am happy to stand.  However, now that the GIS site has launched I will likely have less time to devote to this one in the short term.  If there are others with more time and experience they may be better choices.

Comment: If you would prefer I will happily remove the nomination. I was peeking at your blog earlier and noticed it had a bunch of GIS stuff on it, and I don't want you to be overloaded!

Comment: If there is a small number of candidates, I'm happy to share the load, just don't want to take the place of someone with more time and competence :)

Answer (score 3):

I nominate myself.  I would really like to help grow Webmasters!  I am currently GMT -5 and in a few months I will GMT -4.  That should fit well with the others who are in GMT+ zones and JasonBirch who looks to be in GMT -7.

Comment: Second this.  Yes, during Pacific Daylight Time.  -8 otherwise :)